# Spring RestTemplate, return List<String>

Tags: java, spring, rest, jaxb, resttemplate

Is it possible to return a `List<String>` as a `JAXB` response directly without wrapping it in a response object? E.g.,

```
public List<String> foo(Bar bar) {
    return restTemplate.postForEntity("http://foo.com/bar", bar, List.class);
}
```

Currently I get the error

> Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [my.pkg.Bar]

The HttpMessageConverters *are* properly configured as other GET/POST requests with `Bar` works.

Comment: How does the response look like? How are the strings separated (to a list)? Which format (content-type) do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've only been able to get this working with String[].class as the type.